# Trying to convert a simple C program into an AWK program

Tags: awk, scripting, programming

Hey guys a couple of weeks ago I wrote a C program that prompts the user for the name of a text file and then prompts the user for a word. The program then outputs the input text file with numbers to the left of the text and outputs the number of times the word appears in the text file. It also outputs the matching line numbers in which the words are located.

Here is a sample of it in action:

> Enter the name of a text file: bond.txt
>
> ```
> Enter the pattern to search for: Bond
>
> File contents:
>
> 1) Secret agent Bond had been warned not to tangle with Goldfinger.
>
> 2) But the super-criminal's latest obsession was too strong, too dangerous.
>
> 3) He had to be stopped.
>
> 4) Goldfinger was determined to take possession of half the supply of
>
> 5) mined gold in the world--to rob Fort Knox!
>
> 6) For this incredible venture he had enlisted the aid of the top
>
> 7) criminals in the U.S.A, including a bevy of beautiful thieves from the
>
> 8) Bronx. And it would take all of Bond's unique talents to make it fail--
>
> 9) as fail it must.
>
> There is a match on line 1
>
> There is a match on line 8
>
> 'Bond' appeared 2 times in the file bond.txt.
> ```

Currently I am trying to practice awk programming by repeating the program I did in C but using awk.

Here is what I can muster up so far:

```
BEGIN{
    printf("Enter filename : ")
    getline file < "-"
    while((getline < file)) {
        {print "File Contents:"}
        {printf("%5d) %s\n", NR,$0)}
    }
}
```

What would be the best and efficient way that can allow me to parse the text file line by line to search for the word entered by the user?. Any tips, tricks? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk '/Bond/{c++; print "There is a match on line " NR} END{print "\"Bond\" appeared " c " times in the file " FILENAME}' bond.txt
There is a match on line 1
There is a match on line 8
"Bond" appeared 2 times in the file bond.txt
```

#### How it works

awk implicitly loops over all input lines.

- `/Bond/{c++; print "There is a match on line " NR}`

  For lines matching the regex `Bond`, the counter `c` is incremented and a message is printed showing which line the match is on.  In awk, the number of lines read so far is `NR`.
- `END{print "\"Bond\" appeared " c " times in the file " FILENAME}`

  After the last line is read, a message is printed showing the total number of matches.

#### Multiple line version

For those who like their code spread over many lines:

```
awk '

/Bond/{
    c++
    print "There is a match on line " NR
}

END{
    print "\"Bond\" appeared " c " times in the file " FILENAME
}
' bond.txt
```

#### Displaying the file contents before the file summary

This approach reads through the file twice.  The first time, it prints the version of the file formatted with line numbers.  The second time it prints the summary output:

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{printf("%5d) %s\n", NR,$0);next} /Bond/{c++; print "There is a match on line " FNR} END{print "\"Bond\" appeared " c " times in the file " FILENAME}' bond.txt{,}
    1) Secret agent Bond had been warned not to tangle with Goldfinger.
    2) But the super-criminal's latest obsession was too strong, too dangerous.
    3) He had to be stopped.
    4) Goldfinger was determined to take possession of half the supply of
    5) mined gold in the world--to rob Fort Knox!
    6) For this incredible venture he had enlisted the aid of the top
    7) criminals in the U.S.A, including a bevy of beautiful thieves from the
    8) Bronx. And it would take all of Bond's unique talents to make it fail--
    9) as fail it must.
There is a match on line 1
There is a match on line 8
"Bond" appeared 2 times in the file bond.txt
```

The above differs from the first version two ways.  First, the file is supplied on the command line twice as `bond.txt bond.txt` or, using a bash *brace expansion* trick, as `bond.txt{,}`.

Second, we added the command:

```
FNR==NR{printf("%5d) %s\n", NR,$0);next}
```

This command is only executed if `FNR==NR` where NR is the total the number of lines read so far and FNR is the number of lines read from the current file.  So, when `FNR==NR`, we are reading the file for the first time.  We then `printf` the formatted output and jump to the `next` line, skipping the rest of the commands in the script.

#### Alternative

In this version, we read through the file only once, printing the formatted version while saving the summary information to print at the end:

```
$ awk '{printf("%5d) %s\n", NR,$0)} /Bond/{c++; s=s ORS "There is a match on line " FNR} END{print s; print "\"Bond\" appeared " c " times in the file " FILENAME}' bond.txt
    1) Secret agent Bond had been warned not to tangle with Goldfinger.
    2) But the super-criminal's latest obsession was too strong, too dangerous.
    3) He had to be stopped.
    4) Goldfinger was determined to take possession of half the supply of
    5) mined gold in the world--to rob Fort Knox!
    6) For this incredible venture he had enlisted the aid of the top
    7) criminals in the U.S.A, including a bevy of beautiful thieves from the
    8) Bronx. And it would take all of Bond's unique talents to make it fail--
    9) as fail it must.

There is a match on line 1
There is a match on line 8
"Bond" appeared 2 times in the file bond.txt
```

Comment: Appreciate the pointers John1024. So If I wanted to display the lined-up file contents before any of that output would it be: START{printf("%5d) %s\n", NR,$0)} before awk ' ?

Comment: @Blade.T I just added to the answer two ways to print the formatted version of the file before the summary.

Answer (score 0):

The following should duplicate the function of your sample c code:

```
#!/bin/awk -f
BEGIN{
    printf("Enter the name of a text file: ")
    getline file < "-"
    printf("Enter the pattern to search for: ")
    getline searchfor < "-"
    print "File contents:"
    while (getline < file){
        # NR does not work for files read with getline in this way, so....
        linenum++
        printf("%5d) %s\n",linenum,$0)
        if ($0 ~ searchfor){
            matchcount++
            matches=matches sprintf("There is a match on line %d\n",linenum)
        }
    }
    print matches
    printf("'%s' appeared %d times in file %s.\n",searchfor,matchcount,file)
}
```